# Sign out button functioning but with errors

Tags: php, css, button, logout

I am having trouble attaching a button to my sign out php code and I am not sure why? The log out works fine using the below code but Dreamweaver is highlighting it as a problem?

Here is the problem code:

```
<a href="?simple_auth_action=logout">
<div class="buttonsContent"><input type="submit" class="button slick-3d red" value="Sign out" />
</a>
```

Here is the original code that just displays the word logout:

```
<a href="?simple_auth_action=logout">Logout</a><br />
```

Both work ok but I know that the code has something wrong with it and i have no idea how to fix it?

Thank you for any help, I am very interested to find out how to do this the right way!

Comment: What is the message DW shows with the error? Probably a message about a missing closing tag?

Comment: no message. It just highlights the code in yellow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<a href="?simple_auth_action=logout">
<div class="buttonsContent"><input type="submit" class="button slick-3d red" value="Sign out" /></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Did this and it works! Then had a closer look at your solution and compared it against mine only to realize that the difference is that my code was missing the </div>!!!!! Honestly, I have spent about 2 hours trying to fix this problem! I must have been looking into it to deeply and overlooked the tag! Sorry for wasting any ones time!

Comment: And that's why `Please try this:` only answers are really bad. You first need to compare where the difference is.